# KeneticJS HTML5 Canvas draggable and elements on stage

Tags: html5-canvas, draggable, kineticjs

So i am trying to create a stage where i can have multiple items on it that are draggable.. but when the stage is clicked and dragged all the elements move with it.

So far I can only get one or the other to work by adding the 'draggable' property to either.

Has anyone got a solution for how to get this working?

Here is the JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KHVhU/

I have considered the possibility that I might need to make the containing div draggable using jquery-ui instead of trying to do the whole thing inside the canvas, but ideally wouldnt want to take this route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the solution with the help of the `setDraggable()` function

Updated the JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/KHVhU/1/ :)

Comment: If you add the draggable:true back to the stage, it will be draggable right from the start http://jsfiddle.net/KHVhU/2/

Answer (score 3):

the correct kineticJs library was not included. Use the correct KineticJs below.
http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.4.1.min.js

Now, each individual items will be draggable even with stage.

Comment: there was no link in your answer im afraid

Comment: I have edited the answer and added kinetic JS library link. Please use this link instead.

Comment: Thanks @Uzair Ahmed, this solution does allow for the removal of the setDraggable() function calls.. i dont think 4.4.1 was available when the question was posted.. but im glad Eric has updated :)